# Problem to install apache2-dev on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apache2

Trying to install `apache2-dev` with the command

```
~# sudo apt-get install apache2-dev
```

and get the following:

```
*The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2-dev : Depends: libapr1-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libaprutil1-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: debhelper (>= 9) but it is not going to be installed
 debconf-i18n : Depends: debconf (= 1.5.58ubuntu2) but 1.5.58ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).*
```

Performing

```
~# apt-get -f install
```

get the following

```
*....
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 debconf-i18n : Depends: debconf (= 1.5.58ubuntu2) but 1.5.58ubuntu1 is installed
....*
```

Comment: Have you added any repositories?  If so, try removing them update your package list, and try the apache2-dev install again.  Then add back your repos.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)